# R: Extract first and last names only from a list of names

Tags: r

I am using R for data manipulation. I have a very long list of names that looks like this:

```
"names"

[1] ""                               
[2] "Victoria Marie"                 
[3] "Ori Mann"                     
[4] "Lina Pearl Right"          
[5] "David Berg"                     
[6] "Anthony Lee"                  
[7] "Brian Michael Ingraham"         
[8] "Jay Ling"
```

I want to extract only the first and last names of the whole list into new columns and discard any middle names. How do I do this?
I used the following code:

```
mat  = matrix(unlist(names), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
```

this just runs through all the names in each entry and throws all them into columns in order.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying you want separate columns for the first name and separate column for the last name or just a column with the strings reduced to being the first and last name?

Comment: Yes, first names in one column and last names in another. Thanks.

Comment: Be careful - if your dataset includes many people at all, you're pretty much guaranteed to have someone whose last name will span two or more words, or whose family name is ordered first, or... well, here's [a whole list of things that can go wrong](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Comment: Thanks! But I will probably just ignore anomalies such as those in my analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do this in base R that also deals with the possibility of suffixes. If you discover additional suffixes (e.g., 'II'), you can add them to the vector that follows `%in%`.

```
# some representative data
names <- list("", "Ed Smith", "Jennifer Jason Leigh", "Ed Begley, Jr.")

# use strsplit to get a list of vectors of each name broken into its parts,
# keying off the space between names
names.split <- strsplit(unlist(names), " ")

# make new vectors with the first and last names, based on their position in
# those vectors. for last names, make the result conditional on whether or
# not a recognized suffix is in the last spot, and get rid of any 
# punctuation attached to the last name if there was a suffix.
name.first <- sapply(names.split, function(x) x[1])
name.last <- sapply(names.split, function(x)

  # this deals with empty name slots in your original list, returning NA
  if(length(x) == 0) {

    NA

  # now check for a suffix; if one is there, use the penultimate item
  # after stripping it of any punctuation
  } else if (x[length(x)] %in% c("Jr.", "Jr", "Sr.", "Sr")) {

    gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", x[length(x) - 1])

  } else {

    x[length(x)]

})
```

Results:

```
> name.first
[1] NA         "Ed"       "Jennifer" "Ed"      
> name.last
[1] NA       "Smith"  "Leigh"  "Begley"
```

Comment: Holy cow that's great! It worked perfectly! I can't thank you enough.